# how to sed string with spaces in between?

Tags: sed

before string:

```
file_csv_max_size:         100   # in bytes
```

after string:

```
file_csv_max_size:         200   # in bytes
```

I tried below but did not work..

```
sed 's|file_csv_max_size:         100   # in bytes|file_csv_max_size:         200   # in bytes|' /path/to/file
```

Comment: Try `echo "$string" | sed  's/ 100 / 200 /'`

Answer (score 2):

It could be that some of that spacing is done with TAB characters instead of SPC.

You could do:

```
sed 's|\(file_csv_max_size:[[:space:]]*\)100\([[:space:]]*# in bytes\)|\1200\2|'
```

Where `[[:space:]]*` stands in for any amount of any character classified as whitespace in the locale (so would include SPC, TAB and several others).

We capture what's before and after 100 inside `\(...\)` *capture groups* so they can be referred to as `\1` and `\2` respectively in the replacement.